# Uncaught (in promise): Server error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am getting this exception while using nativescript app.

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Server error
JS: ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
JS: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Server error
JS:     at resolvePromise (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:416:31)
JS:     at /data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:452:17
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:223:37)
JS:     at Object.onInvokeTask (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6197:41)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:222:42)
JS:     at Zone.runTask (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:123:47)
JS:     at drainMicroTaskQueue (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:355:35)
JS: Unhandled Promise rejection: Server error ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Server error
```

This is what i have :

login.component.tns.html

```
<StackLayout class="p-10">
<TextField [(ngModel)]="email" hint="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
<TextField [(ngModel)]="password" hint="Password" secure="true"></TextField>
<Button text="signin" (tap)="login(user)"></Button>
<Button text="signup" (tap)="signup(user)"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

login.component.ts

```
@BaseComponent({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'demo-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent {
login() {
    this.user.password = this.password;
    this.user.username = this.email;
            this.loginService.signin(this.user)
        .subscribe(
        token => {
            this.loginCredentials.setUserId(token.userId);
            this.routerext.navigate(['/list'], {
                transition: {
                    duration: 1000,
                    name: 'slideTop',
                }
            });
        }
        )
};
}
```

login.service.ts

```
export class User {
constructor(
    public username: string,
    public password: string) { }
}

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
signin(user: User) {
            return this.authModelApi.login({
        "email": user.username,
        "password": user.password
    })
        .map(token => token)
        .catch(this.handleError);
};
}
```

when clicking signin button i got this error "server Error". How should i resolve this issue? My web and desktop app working perfectly with this code. am using mongoDb as backend.am new to nativescript and angular2.Any help will really helpfull and highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which HTTP module you use to call this login service method

```
return this.authModelApi.login({
    "email": user.username,
    "password": user.password
})
```

From my experience, it seems for some reasons, you cannot use the native Angular HTTP module to perform HTTP requests. You have to use Nativescript HTTP module. So something like this,

```
import { getJSON, request } from "http";
...

return request({
  url: "....",
  method: "POST"
  headers: [your headers],
  content: [your content]
})


return getJSON("your url here")
```

Check out the official documentation here: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/http.html

Comment: am using nativescript sdk  https://github.com/mean-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder/wiki